# Moderation Log Message Discord JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hello StackOverflow community, this is my first question in need help with for Discord, could someone please edit this code to made this command send a log to *#logs* channel with the following info
1) Title - Moderation Log
2) User the moderation action was performed on
3) What moderation action was performed (in this case ban)
4) Moderator
5) Footer - Proton Servers Bot©2020

````
const { client, config, functions } = require('../index.js');

module.exports.run = async (message, u) => {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.channel.send(functions.errorEmbed('You are not permitted to do this.'));

  if (!u) return message.channel.send(functions.usageEmbed(config.prefix + 'ban <user/id>'));

  const userID = u.match(/[0-9]+/) ? u.match(/([0-9]+)/)[0] : undefined;
  const user = message.guild.members.get(userID);

  if (!user) return message.channel.send(functions.errorEmbed('**' + u + '** is not a valid user.'));

  try {
    await user.ban();
    return message.channel.send(functions.successEmbed('Banned ' + user + ' successfully.'));
  } catch {
    return message.channel.send(functions.errorEmbed('Could not ban ' + user + '. Is their role higher than mine?'));
  }
}

module.exports.description = 'Ban a user.';```
````

Comment: Discord JS Version: 11.5.1
Nodejs Version: v10.20.0

Comment: My discord.js is pretty rusty, although I think your problem can be clarified to help anyone trying to answer your question. For example, you have a chunk of code here; you should explain some parts of it, what works as expected, and what is missing from the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is for discord.js v11. If you want to do this using discord.js v12 then use `MessageEmbed` instead of `RichEmbed` and use `cache` to get the channels collection `message.guild.channels.cache`**

You could use a [`RichEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/RichEmbed) to create the embed you want and then send it to the `log` channel.

First, though, you have to get the `log` channel, there are 2 ways of doing this:

By name: `const logChannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'log')`

Or by ID: `const logChannel = message.guild.channels.get(CHANNEL_ID)`

Then you could use that to send the following embed

```js
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed() // Or new RichEmbed depending on how you're importing things
  .setTitle('Moderation Log')
  .addField('Banned', user)
  .addField('Banned By', message.author)
  .setFooter('Proton Servers Bot©2020')

logChannel.send(embed)
```